# List of transactions from a contract

Tags: transactions, eosjs, rpc, api

I've been on this all day and can't figuring it out on my own so I'm reaching out for your help ;-)

How can I get the list of ALL the transactions associated with an account? I've tried to play around with the "getTransaction" method from eosjs but it only gives me 1 specific transaction. How can I get a list of the various transactions associated with an account?

To be more specific, my goal is to find all the transactions of a specific kind (filtering those I need by their information in the memo which should contain a JSON layout content).

Many thanks in advance for your assistance or anything that can help me unlock the situation.

Comment: `cleos --url https://junglehistory.cryptolions.io:443 get actions <account_name> -1 -1 -j`
this return all the list  transactions done by `account_name`. Here middle -1 means last one transaction related to this account.

Comment: For url you put the where you contract is deployed as in  case of  mine I deployed it on  jungle  test net.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's perfect! I'm not using cleos directly though as I'm using eosjs, an example of my syntax is: eos.getActions({account_name: 'newdexpocket', pos: '3054701', offset: '2'}).then(result => { MY_CODE });

Comment: I'd like the "pos" to be -1 but it's not working, is there a way to start from the last block? Basically the pos isn't the block but the latest action ;-)

Comment: you might be getting  this error : `{ actions: [], last_irreversible_block: 23059136 }
` ?

Comment: This work fine on main net but I think there is error in `/v1/history/get_actions` on jungle test net. If you are gettting some error on main net please share your code You are doing mistake.

Comment: Many many thanks for your feedback, I've double check again but can't understand where the issue is coming from. I get the error message you mention but the code seems fine as it's working with other block numbers. I'm using mainnet. I'm copy / pasting my code bellow, hopefully it will be readable:

Comment: <kbd>const Eos = require('eosjs');

// Connect to a testnet or mainnet
const chain = {
    main: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906',
    jungle: 'XXX',
    sys: 'XXX'
};

const config = {
    expireInSeconds: 60,
    broadcast: true,
    debug: false,
    sign: true,
    httpEndpoint: 'https://eos.greymass.com:443',
    chainId: chain.main, 
};

const eos = Eos(config);

eos.getActions({account_name: 'newdexpocket', pos: -1, offset: '10'}).then(result => {
 
 console.log(result);

});</kbd>

Comment: I  am able to get your transaction from the begining using: pos : 1 , but when i try to use pos: -1 this return empty error. What version of  EOS and eosjs are you using..?

Comment: `"data": {
                                "from": "newdexpocket",
                                "to": "gyztimztg4ge",
                                "quantity": "166.0544 EOS",
                                "memo": "{\"type\":\"cancel-order\",\"symbol\":\"HORUS_EOS\",\"price\":\"0.0022\",\"amount\":\"166.0544\",\"random\":\"181108150743114135\"}"` is this your last transaction? I get this using my code.

Comment: I'm uising EOSJS 16.0.9, not sure what you mean about the EOS version though as I'm connecting straight to a BP (greymass in my example). As for your example, it does work with pos: 1 but that's the very first transaction not the last one and therefore we would need to get all the way through the whole history of transactions to get to the last one :(

Comment: If the pos: -1 doesn't work with eosjs for now, maybe we can skip its usage by finding out the total number of transactions made by that account... is there any easy way to get that information?

Comment: Yes pos is the starting position and offset is the difference. So you should find the range of transaction where you want to have a look. I think there is  also a similar question. If you look at the source code you will  get your doubt clear.